# Is there a delegate method that gets called when the user pressed "Retake" on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UIImagePickerController subclass, and I would like to detect when the user presses the "retake" button.

Is that possible... what delegate method gets called? I looked at the docs but I can't find anything: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html

**EDIT: I am accepting the answer, though this requires you build to OS 3.1**

Comment: Note -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942444/uiimagepicker-cameraoverlayview-appears-on-retake-screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the default controls with:

picker.showsCameraControls = NO;

and implement a cameraOverlayView with your own retake button, that calls the takePicture function on the UIImagePickerController again.