# Is _UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem is private API of UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

In my application, I have to add a custom view (`cameraOverlayView`) on `UIImagePickerController` but not on its preview screen. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942444/uiimagepicker-cameraoverlayview-appears-on-retake-screen) I found the answer how to do that but I am afraid of apple rejection because of using private APIs. So are these :

```
_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem
_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidRejectItem
```

private APIs?

Also if I upload my app for `TestFlight Beta Testing`, does apple check use of private APIs? I am thinking if app successfully uploaded for beta testing then I will not have any problem in uploading final iTunes build.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can identify it by the underscore that is usually used for internal API's to both avoid naming collisions and conforming to the internal interface structure. It may not be detected at this time, but it surely will in later iterations of the review process.